# Создать UPDATE триггер в mysql

Tags: mysql, триггер

Я пытаюсь создать триггер которое брала новые записи (ip,status, его время) из таблицы ***device_history*** и если статус какой-то ip меньше **1** то записал и **обновил** бы строку в ***device_time_off***, а если больше нуля то в ***device_time_on***.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот мой код Инсерта, но пока не понимаю как вместо инсерта UPDATE сделать:

```
DELIMETER //
 CREATE TRIGGER `device_data_time` BEFORE UPDATE ON `devices_history`
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
       IF NEW.status < 1 THEN
        INSERT INTO `device_time_off` (`ip`, `status`, `date`) VALUES (OLD.ip_address, NEW.status, NOW());
         ELSE
           INSERT INTO `device_time_on` (`ip`, `status`, `date`) VALUES (OLD.ip_address, NEW.status, NOW());
         END IF;
    END;//
```

P.S. Извиняюсь если точно не сформулировал вопрос.

Comment: @Mike Я имею ввиду что мне нужно update и чтобы он обновлял записи, а инсерт просто пример... мне нужно вот этот инсерт изменить на update, но не пойму как его сделать... **в device_history они только добавляются, а старые не удаляются**... device_history только очищается от записей каждый месяц.

Comment: @Mike не могли бы мне в виде кода отправить свой ответ, прислать код? я просто хочу чтобы потом с помощью php выводить вот эти время онлайна и оффлайна на сайт... чтобы при :hover (наведении) показывал время его прибытия и ухода... из за этого мне нужен апдейт

Comment: @Mike если я вас правильно понял то вот так? `CREATE DEFINER=`test`@`%` TRIGGER `device_data_time` BEFORE INSERT ON `devices_history` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
       IF NEW.status < 1 THEN
           INSERT INTO `device_time_off` (`ip`, `status`, `date`) VALUES (NEW.ip, NEW.status, NOW());
         ELSE
           INSERT INTO `device_time_on` (`ip`, `status`, `date`) VALUES (NEW.ip, NEW.status, NOW());
         END IF;
    END`

Comment: @Mike есть php файл которое очищает таблицу (с командой TURNCATE), я этот пхп файл поставил на КРОН, каждый месяц первого числа он срабатывает... и да вы правильно поняли, я именно в таблицах on/off хочу держать по одной записи на ip_addres и последную.. Жду вашего ответа, Заранее Спасибо большое

Comment: @Mike хотя да, вы правы status не нужен... уберу его позже :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если структуру таблиц оставить как у вас, то в таблицах off/on никаких дополнительных id не делаем, первичным ключем должен быть ip, в крайнем случае он должен быть уникальным индексом. Поле статус в этих таблицах не нужен, так что я его не привожу. Т.е.:

```
create table device_time_off(
 ip varchar(16) not null,
 `date` datetime not null,
 primary key(ip)
);
```

Тогда триггер выглядит так:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `device_data_time` BEFORE INSERT ON `devices_history`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
 IF NEW.status < 1 THEN
  INSERT INTO `device_time_off` (`ip`,`date`) VALUES (NEW.ip_address, NEW.date)
   ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `date`=NEW.date;
 ELSE
  INSERT INTO `device_time_on` (`ip`,`date`) VALUES (NEW.ip_address, NEW.date)
   ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `date`=NEW.date;
 END IF;
END;
$$
```

Данная форма `insert` добавляет запись если с таким ip записи еще нет и обновляет существующую - если есть.

Но я бы предложил объединить таблицы on/off в одну, с примерно такой структурой

```
create table device_state(
 ip varchar(16) not null,       -- ip
 on_date datetime null,         -- Дата последнего включения
 off_date datetime null,        -- Дата последнего выключения
 last_date datetime not null,   -- Дата последнего события (on/off)
 status tinyint not null,       -- Текущий статус
 primary key(ip)
);
```

И в триггере тогда обновлять ее примерно так:

```
  INSERT INTO `device_state` (ip,`on_date`,`off_date`,`last_date`,`status`)
   VALUES (NEW.ip_address, IF(NEW.status=1,NEW.date,NULL), IF(NEW.status=1,NULL,NEW.date),
           NEW.date, NEW.status)
   ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE last_date=NEW.date,on_date=IF(NEW.status=1,NEW.date,on_date),
                           off_date=IF(NEW.status=1,off_date,NEW.date),status=NEW.status;
```

Получение текущего состояния хоста и дат включения/выключения станет гораздо проще, так как надо будет заглянуть только в одну таблицу и сразу получить все данные.

Comment: всё замечательно работает)) Спасибо Огромноееее)))) Хотел спросить, теперь когда новая запись будет записываться то, и время по новой запишется? или остаётся NULL ом?
http://i.stack.imgur.com/soNOX.jpg

Comment: Когда машина у которой off_date сейчас NULL выключится, то NULL конечно заменится на дату. Т.е. через какое то время у вас у всех машин будут обе даты заполнены. Только у недавно появившихся NULL

Comment: простите за чайниство и глупость с моей стороны, не могли ещё мааленько помочь... Я тут представление (VIEW) сделал, http://i.imgur.com/9miJbP4.jpg , но не пойму почему когда я добавляю `on_date, off_date, last_date` таблица по 8-9 раз повторяются.. посмотрите код, он вроде правильный (О.о): http://i.imgur.com/pcJ0NI4.jpg

Comment: всё перепробовал, но всё равно по несколько раз одно и тоже выводит... :\

Comment: У вас в where нет ни одного условия с упоминанием st, в итоге он к каждой выбираемой записи клеит всю таблицу state. Думаю там по ip-адресу надо ее клеить. И возможно таблицу со статусом стоит клеить по left join, вдруг в ней еще записи нет, а данные в других таблицах есть и они не покажутся